# How to present a UIPicker above a table view?

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a view controller that implements a Table View from a nib file, and its view outlet is connected directly to the Table View in Interface Builder.

In some instances what I'm trying to do is to slide a UIDatePicker into the view from the bottom of the screen, allow the user to make a selection, and then slide it back down.

I've gotten the picker to slide into the screen however my problem is that since I need to add it as a subview like this, `[self.view addSubview:pickerContainer];` what is happening is the picker is being added to the table view and whenever I try to change it's values the entire picker slide up and down with the table.

What should I do to present the DatePicker above the table view?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should present it modally.

```
[pickerContainer setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCurrentContext];
[self presentModalViewController:pickerContainer animated:YES];
```

And put a Done/Select/etc button which does this when called:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

*EDIT:* The other option is to have a parent `UIViewController` with both a table view and another hidden view. Position your hidden view off the bottom of the screen (layered on top of your table view), make sure the controls start disabled, and then you call:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 /* set number of seconds it takes to slide here */
 animations:^
 {
     [pickerContainer setFrame:/*the position you want it to slide in to*/];
 }
 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     [pickerContainer.picker setEnabled:YES]; // only enabled once the animation is done
     [pickerContainer.doneButton setEnabled:YES]; // same for the button to close the view
 }];
```

When the user indicates they are done selecting a date, animate again using `setFrame:` back to the original location of the view to slide it out, and disable the controls.

Comment: Will this cover the entire screen? I would rather only have it cover the bottom of my view...

Comment: Added an alternative solution which might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 3.2 you can set a `inputView` property of your `UITextField` to be the `UIPickerView`. This will replace the keyboard with what ever view you apply to the `inputView` and present this view if that textField becomes firstResponder.